# How can I do left alignment and justification in a textview/webview

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, alignment, uitextview

Can we possible to do both left alignment and justification in same webview or label or texview in iPhone and iPad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes ofcourse there is possibility for left alignment and justification for both label and text view

```
UILabel *label =[[UILabel alloc]init];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
```

and important thing is it will work only from iOS 6.0.

For webview alignment try like this

```
@propert(strong,nonamatic)UIWebView *webData;

[webData loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div align='justify'>%@<div>",DataToLoad] baseURL:nil];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Yohan i thnk this is work on one property at time in uilabels and webview the css is only in justify.I want use both left and justifcation at a time